# Wordpress Blog Management

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a blog site with wordpress. I want users to log in in my site , user should be able to post on the website , but post will be published only when admin approves of it . Please help

Comment: This is how wordpress works. Please read https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: Please consider posting a piece of code of what you've done so far. The SO community will not help you if you do not show the problem you're facing to. Check how to post a correct question right there : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

After login, user add post from admin or front end post form?

if user post from front end then use below code:

```
// Create post object 
$my_post = array(
'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['post_title'] ),
'post_content'  => $_POST['post_content'],
'post_status'   => 'pending', // use draft also 
'post_author'   => 1,
'post_category' => array( 8,39 )
);
// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

after this code, admin can change status from pending to publish.

Comment: If you are asking the question to the user it should be on the comments not as the answer

Comment: User should submit from front end , I have problem how admin will be able  to filter post

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin.
[WP User frontend](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend/)